# Is there a term for

Tags: terminology, words, multiword-expression

I understand what phrase, clause and sentence mean.  But is there a term for a group of words with a clear beginning and end, regardless of whether it's a phrase, clause or sentence?

Comment: Could you [edit] to give some examples? Are you thinking of phrasal verbs like *put up with*? What about idioms like *sweep under the table* which can be broken up (*sweep **those uncomfortable facts** under the table*)?

Comment: Are you talking about a group of words that form a cohesive grammatical unit?

Comment: Yes, "substring". If you want it to be specifically aligned to word-ends, you can say "word substring" as opposed to some other level of analysis.

Comment: Is your question about runs of words that may not be phrases, like "for a group of with with a clear beginning and"?

Answer (score 3):

The general term for any chunk of language that's self-contained -- a phrase, a clause, a sentence -- is ***Constituent***. Syntax is all about constituents, because syntactic processes only apply to constituents of utterances. No syntax rules apply to random strings of words; they're not language.

For instance, Extraposition is a typical syntactic rule, which moves heavy clauses and phrases from subject position to the end of a sentence, leaving behind a dummy (non-referential) pronoun *it* to hold the Subject slot.

- ***For him to stay late** would be a bad idea.*
  == Extraposition ==>
  *It would be a bad idea **for him to stay late**.*

*For him to stay late* is a constituent, an infinitive clause, with the infinitive subject noun phrase constituent *him* marked by the complementizer *for*, and the infinitive verb phrase constituent marked by the complementizer *to*; and the whole constituent is moved as a unit by the transformation to the end, where it's easier to process. The *it* is necessary because a sentence constituent must have a subject constituent, even though it doesn't have to mean anything.

For more details on constituents and how to identify them, take a look at chapter 3 "Tests for Constituency", [in this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English/k6-C5AWWqjQC?hl=en&gbpv=1).

Answer (score 2):

There are some terms of interest in that field, the most general of them is
**collocation** assuming no specific relationship between the words. Then, there is **multi word expression** assuming that the words form a semantic unit, and there is **formulaic expression** assuming that the word have a common pragmatic function. There is also the term **translation unit** from translation studies, describing a group of words treated as a unit for translation.

Comment: Nice answer. I suspect the OP is asking about a syntactic unit, though.